Why is FileExists failing? And if I use Exec anyway then that fails?
I am stumped with this!
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

function GetFileAttributes(lpFileName: string): DWORD;
  external 'GetFileAttributes{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall'; 

function GetLastError() : LongInt;
 external 'GetLastError@kernel32.dll stdcall';

const
  INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES = $FFFFFFFF;

{ Triggers the uninstaller for specified app }
function UninstallOldVersion( AppID: String ): Boolean;
var
    LastError: LongInt;
    sUninstallerPath: String;
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    sUninstallerPath := GetUninstallerPath(AppID);
    Log('Old uninstaller: ' + sUninstallerPath);
    if (FileExists(sUninstallerPath)) then 
    begin
        MsgBox('We need to uninstall the old application first. Uninstaller: ' + sUninstallerPath, mbError, MB_OK);
        Log('We need to uninstall the old application first. Uninstaller: ' + sUninstallerPath);

        Exec(sUninstallerPath, '/VERYSILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
        if (ResultCode <> 0) then
        begin
            Log('There was an error running the uninstaller: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode));
            Result := False;
        end;

        Result := True;
    end
    else begin
    LastError := GetLastError;
    MsgBox(sUninstallerPath + ' does not exist - '  +
        Format('System Error. Code: %d. %s', [
               LastError, SysErrorMessage(LastError)]), mbError, MB_OK);
               
        MsgBox('Unable to locate the old uninstaller: ' + sUninstallerPath, mbError, MB_OK);
        Log('Unable to locate the old uninstaller: ' + sUninstallerPath);
        Result := False;
    end;

    Result := False;
end;

It says that sUninstallerPath does not exist. It does.

That is what GetLastError says. But the file exist!
If I use a console window I understandably find that I need to use quotes:

So I don't know if that is part of the issue?
If I do this directly:
Exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant\unins000.exe', '/VERYSILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);

It works. So this is weird.
